# Algorithm question for c# (displaying every number of digits using string.split)

Tags: c#, algorithm, split, numbers, digits

Let's say we have integer numbers 1 to 20. I have to print out something like this:

```
Number of 1: 13
Number of 2: 5
Number of 3: 5
.
.
Number of 9: 2
```

I used string.split method [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCFeP.png).

How can I implement this with integers array and moving forward with for loops? Or is there any better way to solve this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This is my first question ever on stackoverflow so I'm still learning

Comment: Your `str` does not contain any digit (`"The Engineering Projects"`), it is quite unclear what you are asking. Also your sample will only display `"The"` and `"Engineering"` (skipping `"Projects"`), as you use `count < strArr.Length-1` in your `for` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any better way to solve this?

Yes, there are better ways to do what you are trying to achieve.

Here is my attempt:

I would suggest using `Dictionary<int, int>` to store the integer and its count with the digit.

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 20) //Iterate from 1 to 20
            .SelectMany(x => x.ToString()) //create an array from [1..20]
            .GroupBy(x => x)  //Group by element, so that you will get count
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count()); //Store it in dictionary

foreach(var item in result)
    Console.WriteLine($"Number of {item.Key} : {item.Value}");
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y3AkJv)

Comment: @Tanokt, I am glad my solution works for you. Just a note: Please update your question with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others will get the benefit from it. Currently, it is really hard to understand you are expecting and what are your inputs